# generalizing ajax call for this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I created an ajax request which is here

```
        function postForm(url, data) {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(data);

           xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                const DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
                const OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
                if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === OK) {
                        const requestMessage = xhr.responseText;
                        console.log(requestMessage); // 'This is the returned text.'
                        const success = requestMessage.search(1);
                        const error = requestMessage.search(0);
                        if(success !== -1) {
                            console.log("success");
                            removeClass(modal, 'is-active');
                            closeModal();
                            window.location.reload();
                        } else {
                            console.log("error");
                            const parent = findAncestor(this, 'folder');
                            const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
                            errorMessage.className = "errorMessage";
                            errorMessage.innerHTML = requestMessage;
                            errorMessage.innerHTML = requestMessage.replace('0','');
                            parent.append(errorMessage);
                        };
                    } else if (xhr.status === INT_ERROR) {
                         console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

and im having an issue with this part. I want be able to generalize this. when a user presses a button that calls this ajax call, the ajax calls the parent of what they clicked and finds the ancestor and adds errorMessage to the parent of that element. how can i generalize this ajax?

```
                        console.log("error");
                        const parent = findAncestor(this, 'folder');
                        const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
                        errorMessage.className = "errorMessage";
                        errorMessage.innerHTML = requestMessage;
                        errorMessage.innerHTML =                      
                        requestMessage.replace('0','');
                        parent.append(errorMessage);
```

Comment: So is the goal to simply display an error message?

Comment: Why aren't you using `$.ajax()`? You have jQuery in the tags.

Comment: Writing ajax by hand every time you need to use is about the same thing as hoping for your own death. If you're going to interact with native XMLHttpRequest, at least write a small abstraction procedure so you don't have to duplicate your code every time.

Comment: Pass the clicked element to `postForm()`. Then use `$(clicked).closest('.folder')` to find the ancestor with `class="folder"`.

Comment: BTW, inside the `onreadystatechange` function, `this` is the XHR, so `findAncestor(this)` makes no sense.

Comment: yes i need to show an error message on when a user selects this(element)